# How to set up django debug toolbar along with static files and media files in URLs (DJANGO 2.0)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, static, django-debug-toolbar

How can i set up django debug toolbar when using django static files and media files

Below is my configuration in urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),]
```

I am not sure whether the line with 'elif' is the right way to do it.
(The web app crashes when i try to launch it in dev)

Comment: `elif` with the same condition as in the `if` does not make any sense for sure. Also, an assignment in the second part **overwrites** urlpatterns instead of adding to it.

Comment: you should add to `urlpatterns` like for static/media.  Also I don't see the closing `]`

Comment: @dirkgroten I have updated my codes. Is it what you referred to?

Comment: no, `+=`. You're extending the patterns, not replacing them.

Comment: @dirkgroten got you. thank you for pointing out the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will never go to elif block if first condition evaluates to `Ture` and you are never going to get toolbar in DEBUG mode. Accroding to docs you should do something like this.

> ```
> if settings.DEBUG:
>     import debug_toolbar
>     urlpatterns = [
>         path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
>
>         # For django versions before 2.0:
>         # url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
>
>     ] + urlpatterns
> ```

So your final code should be (As you have additional piece)

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls))
    ]
```